# Sqlite query to get rows of the next 30 days, (BETWEEN now AND now+30days)

Tags: android, sqlite

Assume you have a table with the following columns (all integers)

```
taskId | day | month | year
------------------------
1      | 4    | 4     | 2016
1      | 3    | 5     | 2016
1      | 12   | 5     | 2016
1      | 30   | 5     | 2016
```

assume that the date now is 4/4/2016
How to get records, in Sqlite query, that are between now and the next 30 days.
 Means, the next 30 days tasks.

so the result should be,

```
1      | 4    | 4     | 2016    << today is 4/4/2016
1      | 3    | 5     | 2016
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert these columns into SQLite's default date format, use `printf()`:

```sql
printf("%04d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day)
```

You can then use the built-in date functions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE printf(...) BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now', '+30 days');
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

I have to say that working with `date` would have been waaaay better, or also working with the `date.getTime` which returns a `long`.

**Said that**

from java side you will have to do something like this:

```
Caendar c = Calendar.getIstance();

int currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; //it's 0 based
int currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
int nextMonthDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int nextMonthMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; //it's 0 based
int nextMonthYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String myQuery = String.Format("select * from myTable where (day >= {0} and month >= {1} and year >= {2}) and ( day < {3} and month <= {4} and year <= {5})", currentDay, currentMonth, currentYear, nextMonthDay, nextMonthMonth, nextMonthYear);
```

This will take all rows where date is >= current and date is <= next month

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the best way that I am going to follow. Thanks